# Connection problem Raspbbery Pico

Tags: pi-pico

I have a problem connecting raspberry pico. I tried the standard connection before you connect with the usb cable holding the bootsel key. But nothing happens. Pico does not connect to the computer. What other solution can there be? Did I accidentally destroy it? Thank you for your answer. Greetings.

Comment: *Pico does not connect to the computer* - how have you determined this?

Comment: I connected Pico to my Win10 PC with USB cable to install, and everything went smoothly and done in 3 minutes.  It is important to download the most update to date file.

Comment: Ah, one more thing. You should not use phone charger USB cable which has not data wires. Also when you plug in the USB cable, you should find the usually COM3 in Control Panel. Otherwise USB cable is not detected.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the usb cable was a problem.

Now I have a problem with this:

```
`File "C:\Users\matij\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\workbench.py", 
line 1708, in event_generate
    handler(event)
  File "C:\Users\matij\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\shell.py", line 433, in _handle_program_output
    self._update_visible_io(None)
  File "C:\Users\matij\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\shell.py", line 512, in _update_visible_io
    self._apply_io_event(data, stream_name)
  File "C:\Users\matij\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\shell.py", line 555, in _apply_io_event
    self.active_extra_tags.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list'
```

I use the Thonny program.
However, I also noticed that the usb cable does not use com3 but com10.
What's the problem here?

Comment: This is not related to the question - I would open a new question at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) for the `IndexError` exception. Don't forget to post your _entire_ code there. Also please don't forget to mark your question as the answer :)

Comment: It is not guaranteed to be com 3 on your system.

Comment: (1) Ha, I only use COM3 as an example. WinPC usually finds a free port and give me a number, sequentially. Some times I go up to COM 20 or COM 30 and used a clean up tool to reset to COM3 say. (2) Yes, Thonny seems to have a teething problem. I once tried installing something, and Thonny put it in /temp and report error. I then tried again and Thonny seemed clever and install it in Thonny/lib. (3) I installed Thonny myself before installing any Pico, and Thonny is clever to seamless glue things up.

Comment: I don't know what is "matij" and "workbench". I tried perhaps 10 of the official demos, mostly using Tom's Hardware tutorial and everything went smoothly. If you want to install some software, go to Thonny Package Management (or similar name I forgot) and search your software. If you find it then good, otherwise you need to do some fiddling, but often bad luck for me. :(

Comment: BTW, I learnt many Pico tricks from a Swiss guy. If you have not watched his videos. Here it is: (1) Rpi Pico vs ESP32 and STM32 - 2021jan31
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVHCllbN3bQ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVHCllbN3bQ. Happy watching. Cheers.

Comment: I solved the matter. Thanks tlfong01. I had to do a reset. It works nicely now. It also works beautifully in Thonny.

Comment: How nice to hear your good news. Have a great pico project. Cheers.

Comment: Let me tell you another piece of news. If I unplugged the Raspberry Pico via USB and then reconnected the power, and pressed Stop / Restart, I still had an error. The problem was the main.py file in Pico. She was broken. When I deleted it. The errors no longer occurred. Now it works just like in the beginning. 
Thank you again for your help!